# Find first element in list where value is greater than a constant

Tags: python

I have a list and I have a constant, and I want to know which elements in the list is greater than a constant.

```
ls = [2, 1, 0, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1]
constant = 1.5
```

So I simply did:

```
ls >= constant
```

I expect it to return:

```
[TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE]
```

But it returned an error!!!

```
TypeError                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-92-91099ebca512> in <module>
----> 1 ls > constant

TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'float'
```

How to python compare a vector to a simple constant value?

Answer (score 5):

You can use a list comprehension to assess values whilst looping.

You need to loop when comparing elements as you cannot compare a `list` to an `integer`.

```
output = [x > constant for x in ls]
#[True, False, False, False, True, True, False, True, False]
```

Comment: Casting to float doesn't make a difference really... It should work without it

Comment: @12944qwerty Updated, I misread the error.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) for this and lambda functions.

```py
print(list(map(lambda n:n>=constant, ls)))
```

The reason your code doesn't work is that a list and float cannot be compared. In order for comparisons to work, they need to be of the same object (or the magic methods be pre-defined to work with custom objects).

Answer (score 1):

The most Pythonic (IMO) way to get the list you describe is with a list comprehension:

```
>>> [n >= constant for n in ls]
[True, False, False, False, True, True, False, True, False]
```

It's almost the same as what you wrote, but you want to do the comparison on each individual `n` value `for n in ls`, rather than on `ls` itself.

If you want the actual values, that's a very similar expression:

```
>>> [n for n in ls if n >= constant]
[2, 3, 2, 2]
```

In this case, the actual value in the list is `n`, but we only include it at all `if n >= constant`.